# Phonegap PushNotification to open a specific app page

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I am doing pushnotification for both Android/IOS.I have used a phonegap push-plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin, it seems to work great.

I am receiving message on my device now the problem is When i click on the received message it goes to app index.html page.But i want to open someother page eg home.html when i clicked the message and in home.html  i will be showing the message.

How to achieve this?

MyPhoneGapActivity.java

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); 
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
    }
}
```

index.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pushNotification;

    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

            if( $("#home").length > 0)
            {
                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else
            {
                navigator.app.backHistory();
            }
        }, false);

        try 
        { 
            pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});     // required!
            } else {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
            }
        }
        catch(err) 
        { 
            txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
            txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
            alert(txt); 
        } 
    }

    // handle APNS notifications for iOS
    function onNotificationAPN(e) {
        if (e.alert) {
             $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
             navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
        }

        if (e.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(e.sound);
            snd.play();
        }

        if (e.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
        }
    }

    // handle GCM notifications for Android
    function onNotificationGCM(e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
            }
            break;

            case 'message':
                // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                if (e.foreground)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                    my_media.play();
                }
                else
                {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                    if (e.coldstart)
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    else
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }

                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            break;

            case 'error':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
            break;

            default:
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
            break;
        }
    }

    function tokenHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
        // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    }

    function successHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
    }

    function errorHandler (error) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this,

Step 1 : Open your GCMIntentService.java file

Check for the method onMessage

in that method you will find from here they are passing the intent to your MyPhoneGapActivity.java ...Now what you have to do is you pass some extra information....
Passing some extra information to the intent

Check for this line

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyPhoneGapActivity.class);
//here you pass the information
notificationIntent.putExtra ("url",url);
```

Can you see above i have passed extra information url ...for the complete code see below

```
  protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        boolean foreground = this.isInForeground();

        extras.putBoolean("foreground", foreground);

        if (foreground){
            PushHandlerActivity.sendToApp(extras);
        }else{
            String message = extras.getString("message");
            String title = extras.getString("title");
            Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, message, System.currentTimeMillis() );
            notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            String url = "notify";

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyPhoneGapActivity.class);
            //here you pass the information
            notificationIntent.putExtra ("url",url);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);
        }
    }
  }
```

Step 2:

In your MyPhoneGapActivity.java

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); 

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = extras.getString("url");
        if(message == "notify"){
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/home.html", 10000);
        }else{
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it now when you click the notification it will load the home.html file:-)

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same thing with Apple push notification? I attached Phonegap Apple push notification plugin and want to change page when user click on notification.

Comment: every thing that I am writing in this main activity class is disappearing after every cordova build. what should I do to keep my changes?

Comment: @sdg: Really helpful that was. One problem is, when the condition is satisfied `if(message == "notify")` the screen goes white after the splash screen. One thing to notice is, in the false condition it goes fine.

Comment: Is there a way to do this is pure javascript? Perhaps a timeout and window.location.assign('/foo/bar')?

Comment: It would be simpler and more flexible to append url hash to the launchUrl, e.g., `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#custompage` or some parameters, e.g. `file:///android_asset/www/index.html?page=custom`. There is no need for `home.html`. Just use javascript to process `window.location.hash` or the url parameters when your device is ready.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used this plugin before but it looks like it passes a `message` in the notification that you can process in your application. It seems therefore that in your `index.html` you could read this message and if it contains some certain string, redirect to `main.html` or wherever you want to go. You could do this while a splash screen is still visible or something so that the user doesn't see a jarring page redirect.

Comment: I do something very similar to this for my App.  I pass a parameter to the notification and if I find that parameter I open a different page or call a function or ....

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same problem after some research finally Got My Solution, If any one Have Same Problem .Please Follow these link

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213