# Cordova pushnotification open specific page in android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

Refer from this question ([Phonegap PushNotification to open a specific app page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689092/phonegap-pushnotification-to-open-a-specific-app-page)) it is possible to open a specfic page in cordova app when clicking on push notification. From the answer, i cant see the  specified code in my plugin. Here is my code from GCMIntentService.java file

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

        // Extract the payload from the message
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            // if we are in the foreground, just surface the payload, else post it to the statusbar
            if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
                extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
                PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
            }
            else {
                extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

                // Send a notification if there is a message
                if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
                    createNotification(context, extras);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
    {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String appName = getAppName(this);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
            try {
                defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setDefaults(defaults)
                .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        String message = extras.getString("message");
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
        }

        String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
        if (msgcnt != null) {
            mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
        }

        int notId = 0;

        try {
            notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private static String getAppName(Context context)
    {
        CharSequence appName = 
                context
                    .getPackageManager()
                    .getApplicationLabel(context.getApplicationInfo());

        return (String)appName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError - errorId: " + errorId);
    }
```

.Please help

Answer (score 0):

in  the exsample you´re linking, they´re getting an extra called `message` from the intent that invokes the activity in the `onCreate` method. Then they´re `calling super.loadUrl()`.

Override the `onCreate` of your PhoneGap activity and open the url you may pass in in the intent you´re setting in the notification extras.

Comment: you already linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689092/phonegap-pushnotification-to-open-a-specific-app-page