# how to open secific page onclick on notification in phonegap 3.6 by using pushplugin

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/1979d97) in my Phonegap Application. I don't have any problem getting Notification from the server, but i need when i click on notification, then i want to open a specific page like "home.html" page or "information.html" page but it's directly open default "index.html" page.

I try [Phonegap PushNotification to open a specific app page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16689948/2143446) but I am little bit Confuse that how application know that (message == "notify")  to open a specific page, it is not define in answer. And I think answer belongs to old version of Phonegap Pushplugin.

Pls help Me. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my solution, If anyone has the same problem. Please follow this link.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213

Comment: Thanks for this, nice solution, i could only get this to work if the app was open but now seems to work fine